# JavaScript - Removing last index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using a third party API to graph data on Highcharts.

This API returns data depending on the month we are in. For example, it returns data about March, April, May etc...

`graphArrOne` returns an array length of 251

`graphArrTwo` returns an array length of 250. `graphArrayTwo` only returns data up until April while `graphArrayOne` returns data up until May.

I am creating a condition to compare both lengths and if so slice the last index of the greater array.

My issue is how can I remove the last index of an array without specifying which index to slice? For example, if the API is updated an `graphArrOne` data now shows June, while `graphArrayTwo` shows May. I will like to still slice the last month.

Is there a way to remove the last index of an array without specifying which index?

My expected outcome is if `graphArrOne` is larger then `graphArrTwo` remove the last index from `graphArrOne`

My code:

```
if (graphArrOne.length > graphArrTwo) { 
    graphArrOne.slice(250,251) // this is what I'm trying to do.
}
```

Comment: You can set the `.length` property of an array to `.length - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `pop()`

```
if (graphArrOne.length > graphArrTwo.length) { 
    graphArrOne.pop()
}
```

The `pop()` method removes the last element from an `array` and returns that element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop` to remove last item of array.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

if(arr1.length > arr2.length) {
  arr1.pop()
}

if(arr2.length > arr1.length) {
  arr2.pop()
}

console.log(arr1);

console.log(arr2)
```